# JavaScript nested function returning the id of only the first div, when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this function that returns when an an ajax has been called, however the function returns only the id of the first div in the post and repeats the same id number for the next elements or div tags. However, when the function is used on click with specified $(this) it returns the unique div of the other elements. Please help. Here's the code.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".likeTypeAction", function () {
    var reaction_id = $('.likeTypeAction');
    var reactionType = $(this).attr("data-reaction");
    var reactionName = $(this).attr("original-title");
    var rel = $(this).parent().parent().attr("rel");
    var x = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var sid = x.split("reaction");
    var id_post = sid[1];
    var htmlData = '<i class="' + reactionName.toLowerCase() + 'IconSmall likeTypeSmall" ></i>' + reactionName;
    var dataString = 'id_post=' + id_post + '&rid=' + reactionType;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxReaction',
        type: "post",
        data: {"done": 1, "id_post": id_post, "rid": reactionType},
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert(id_post);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            displayReaction();
        },

    });
});

function displayReaction() {
    a = $("#reactionEmoji");
    var cls = $(this.a).parent().attr('class');
    var n = cls.split("reaction");
    var reactionNew = n[1];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxReaction',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            "getReaction": 1, "reactionNew": reactionNew
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            alert(reactionNew);
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    })
}

myInstance = new displayReaction();
```

```html
echo '<div id="reaction" class="reaction' . $id_post . '">
    <div id="reactionEmoji">nothing</div>
</div>';
echo'<div class="reaction-action">';
echo '<div rel="unlike" c="undefined" id="reaction' . $id_post . '" class="likeDiv">
    <div class="tooltipster-content">
        <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Like" data-reaction="1">
            <i class="likeIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Amei" data-reaction="2">
            <i class="ameiIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Haha" data-reaction="3">
            <i class="hahaIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Uau" data-reaction="4">
            <i class="uauIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Triste" data-reaction="5">
            <i class="tristeIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="likeTypeAction last" original-title="Grr" data-reaction="6">
            <i class="grrIcon likeType"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="tooltipster-arrow-top tooltipster-arrow" style="">
        <span class="tooltipster-arrow-border" style="margin-bottom: -1px; border-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);"></span>
        <span style="border-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"></span>
    </div>
</div>';
```

Comment: Please actually post your code

Comment: i am so sorry, i'm new at this

Comment: Ok, thank you! i'll just edit it

Comment: `var reaction_id = $('.likeTypeAction');` - this just selects within the whole document, this has no limitation whatsoever to your current context. Doesn’t make much sense anyway, since your delegated event is bound to that class to begin with, so `$(this)` will refer to that already.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your respose. CBroe, the divs all have their unique post id generated through php. The first java script code does exactly what it's supposed to and that is split the div reaction with the associated number. However, the nested function which is supposed to be a second call selects only the first element's div, as per for each div it's only getting the id of the first div in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code.

I suppose the PHP code you provided is in some kind of loop : $id_post suggests your looping through some data and printing this HTML for each post.

If it is inside a loop, you are going to have, in your document, for each loop :

```
<div id="reaction" class="reaction' . $id_post . '">
    <div id="reactionEmoji">nothing</div>
</div>
```

You can't have several HTML elements with the same id.

And since you are using the `reactionEmoji` id in your `displayReaction` function, you may want to fix that :

```
function displayReaction() {
    a = $("#reactionEmoji");
    var cls = $(this.a).parent().attr('class');
    var n = cls.split("reaction");
    var reactionNew = n[1];
    /* .... */
    alert(reactionNew);
}
```

In the snippet below :

- I replaced your PHP code with 3 HTML generated codes
- I added some labels to replace your icon (we didn't have your CSS)
- I made both divs ids unique
- I corrected your `displayReaction` function so that it takes the id of the reaction you want to display as a parameter.

I'm not sure it does what you want it to do, but it should help you solve your issues.

```js
$(document).on("click",".likeTypeAction",function()
{

var reaction_id = $('.likeTypeAction');
var reactionType=$(this).attr("data-reaction");
var reactionName=$(this).attr("original-title");
var rel=$(this).parent().parent().attr("rel");
var x=$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

var sid=x.split("reaction");
var id_post =sid[1];
var htmlData='<i class="'+reactionName.toLowerCase()+'IconSmall likeTypeSmall" ></i>'+reactionName;
var dataString = 'id_post='+ id_post +'&rid='+reactionType;

displayReaction(id_post);     
/*
$.ajax({
url: 'ajaxReaction',
type: "post",
data: {"done":1, "id_post":id_post, "rid":reactionType}, 
beforeSend: function(){alert(id_post);},
success: function(data){
                   
      },

});*/
});

function displayReaction(id_post){
    a = $("#reactionEmoji" + id_post);
    var cls = $(this.a).parent().attr('class');
    
    var n = cls.split("reaction");
    
    var reactionNew = n[1];

    $.ajax({
     url: 'ajaxReaction',
     type: "post",
     data: {
         "getReaction":1,"reactionNew":reactionNew
     },
     beforeSend: function(){
         alert(reactionNew);
     },
     success: function(data){

     }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="reaction" class="reaction1"> 
 <div id="reactionEmoji1">nothing</div>
 <div class="reaction-action">
  <div rel="unlike" c="undefined" id="reaction1" class="likeDiv">
   <div class="tooltipster-content">
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Like" data-reaction="1">
     <i class="likeIcon likeType">like</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Amei" data-reaction="2">
     <i class="ameiIcon likeType">Amei</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Haha" data-reaction="3">
     <i class="hahaIcon likeType">Haha</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Uau" data-reaction="4">
     <i class="uauIcon likeType">Uau</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Triste" data-reaction="5">
     <i class="tristeIcon likeType">Triste</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction last" original-title="Grr" data-reaction="6">
     <i class="grrIcon likeType">Grr</i>
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltipster-arrow-top tooltipster-arrow" style="">
    <span class="tooltipster-arrow-border" style="margin-bottom: -1px; border-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);;"/>
    <span style="border-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>


<div id="reaction" class="reaction2"> 
 <div id="reactionEmoji2">nothing</div>
 <div class="reaction-action">
  <div rel="unlike" c="undefined" id="reaction2" class="likeDiv">
   <div class="tooltipster-content">
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Like" data-reaction="1">
     <i class="likeIcon likeType">like</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Amei" data-reaction="2">
     <i class="ameiIcon likeType">Amei</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Haha" data-reaction="3">
     <i class="hahaIcon likeType">Haha</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Uau" data-reaction="4">
     <i class="uauIcon likeType">Uau</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Triste" data-reaction="5">
     <i class="tristeIcon likeType">Triste</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction last" original-title="Grr" data-reaction="6">
     <i class="grrIcon likeType">Grr</i>
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltipster-arrow-top tooltipster-arrow" style="">
    <span class="tooltipster-arrow-border" style="margin-bottom: -1px; border-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);;"/>
    <span style="border-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>

<div id="reaction" class="reaction3"> 
 <div id="reactionEmoji3">nothing</div>
 <div class="reaction-action">
  <div rel="unlike" c="undefined" id="reaction3" class="likeDiv">
   <div class="tooltipster-content">
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Like" data-reaction="1">
     <i class="likeIcon likeType">like</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Amei" data-reaction="2">
     <i class="ameiIcon likeType">Amei</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Haha" data-reaction="3">
     <i class="hahaIcon likeType">Haha</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Uau" data-reaction="4">
     <i class="uauIcon likeType">Uau</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction" original-title="Triste" data-reaction="5">
     <i class="tristeIcon likeType">Triste</i>
    </span>
    <span class="likeTypeAction last" original-title="Grr" data-reaction="6">
     <i class="grrIcon likeType">Grr</i>
    </span>
   </div>
   <div class="tooltipster-arrow-top tooltipster-arrow" style="">
    <span class="tooltipster-arrow-border" style="margin-bottom: -1px; border-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);;"/>
    <span style="border-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response, ill give it a try and get back to you

Comment: The above code you gave, worked fine. However, that's not the part i had and issue with. The second function displayReaction(){ is supposed to be the output from when the first function is clicked, the second function sends a request to the mysql database to get the result. But the problem i have is that for each post id in the second function $(this) is alerting me with the first, which  is one for the whole other tags.

Comment: Well, this is the issue I tried to adress with the changes I described in my answer. Check the snippet, the alerts comes from the "second" function and it's alerting the right id.

Comment: my function is telling me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! i didn't replace my html with the corrected one and it works. i i wish i could do so much more than up vote you